# How do I plot linear decision boundary in matlab

Tags: matlab, boundary

[plotted two different dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu5QP.png)

I have 2 different dataset that have different mu and sigma, and X vector such as [1.8; 1.8]. And also I know probability of each classes that P(ω1)= P(ω2) = 1/2
I want to ploting linear decision boundary between these two dataset but I don't have any idea have to do. My code is down below, here

```
X = [1.8; 1.8];
u1 = [1;1]; u2 = [3;3];
s1 = [1 0;0 1]; s2 = [1 0;0 1];
Pr1 = 1/2;
Pr2 = 1/2;

r = mvnrnd(u1,s1,500);
plot(r(:,1), r(:,2), '+r');
hold on

r = mvnrnd(u2,s2,500);
plot(r(:,1), r(:,2), '+b');
hold on
grid on

W1 = (u1')/(s1(1,1))^2;
W10 = (u1'*u1)/(-2*s1(1,1)) + log(Pr1);
g1 = W1'.*X + W10;

W2 = (u2')/(s2(1,1))^2;
W20 = (u2'*u2)/(-2*s2(1,1)) + log(Pr2);
g2 = W2'.*X + W20;
```

Is there someone who can give any idea to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved decision problem, in detailed

First I defined parametric function with parameters x1 and x2 such as

```
g = @(x1,x2)
```

then in order to plotting decision boundary realized that g1-g2 = 0 equation such as

```
e = @(x1,x2) (W1*[x1;x2] + w10 - W2*[x1;x2] - w20)
ezplot(g, [-xlim xlim -ylim ylim])
```

and done

Comment: I don't understand the solution, I was able to plot using this code `g = @(x1,x2) (W1*[x1;x2] + W10 - W2*[x1;x2] - W20);
fimplicit(g);` But I got this warning. `Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly vectorize your
function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input arguments. ` Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to calculate two points of the decision boundary you want to plot.

```
W1_W2 = W2 - W1; % vector from W1 to W2
W1_W2_average = (W2 + W1)/2; % point in the middle between W1 and W2
W1_W2_orthogonal = [-W1_W2(2) W1_W2(1)]; % vector orthogonal to W1_W2
points = [W1_W2_average - 2*W1_W2_orthogonal; W1_W2_average + 2*W1_W2_orthogonal]; % Two points on the line you want to plot
plot(points(:, 1), points(:, 2)); %plot the line
```

Note that I am not very familiar with classification problems. I might have forgotten some terms in the calculation of the decision boundary.